# Is there an EU law that a hotel can't kick you out if you're sick?

Tags: europe, health, legal, accommodation, eu

Someone told me that there was an EU law that said that if a doctor certifies you as sick (to some degree) and you're staying in a hotel, that the hotel cannot kick you out of the room.

**Update** Just to clarify, I don't believe there would ever be a law that says you're allowed to stay for free! I'm wondering if you were sick in a hotel and the hotel has the room booked out for when you leave, can they kick you out of the hotel?

Is this true? And if so, what are the details of this EU law?

Comment: You'll likely have to pay the "rack-rate" if you extend your stay in a manner like this, which can often be a lot more than you paid for your initial reservation.... (I'm not sure if the doctor thing is EU-wide, but at least some places do have it)

Comment: If such a rule was there, then logically all hotels would ask you for a health certificate before checking it... or even the hotel will provide a medical check up service upon checking in to make sure people are healthy so they won't have to be stuck with you... Maybe they will provide it as a courtesy to some ill visitors in certain situations...

Comment: There is definitely no EU-wide law on this. For example in the UK you would just be admitted to hospital.

Comment: There is no such a thing as **EU law**. There are EU directives, which should be taken in account by member countries in their local laws. Although I doubt that directive covering this particular case would exist. EU directives usually are very broad and generic.

Comment: @vartec: But there are **EU regulations**. They have legal power in every member state as soon as they enter in force. Just as a national law. There is neither a regulation on this specific topic. This matter is regulated by national laws.

Comment: Yes there are no "EU laws" per se, but an EU directive is de facto (eventually) a law, and is commonly called "EU Law"

Comment: Nope. A directive is not a law, even not "de facto". A directive is a set of principles and rules that have to be transposed into national law. This has to be done by the member states. A regulation is in fact a law. It has egal power in every member state as soon as it enters in force. Do you get the difference?

Comment: Yes, OK, this is a pedantic argument. So when I ask "Is there an EU law…" I'm really asking "Is there an EU Regulation or Directive…"

Comment: Maybe pedantic, but it doesn't change anything. There is neither the one not the other.

Comment: I suspect that once you book into a hotel, the hotel isn't allowed to do anything that puts you into danger. If you are in such a bad state that being kicked out with your suitcase puts you into danger, they can't kick you out. They might call an ambulance or the police to take care of you if there are no relatives or anyone else to help. I doubt there is a specific law, but general principles.

Answer (score 10):

I'd be fairly sure that common sense can answer this.

Let's consider how sick you are.

1) Feel ill, but not sick enough that a doctor will claim you're SICK.  So there's no actual evidence. A hotel is not going to keep you there for free, or everyone would claim this.

2) Ill enough that, say, you can't go to work, but don't need to go to hospital.  A doctor can usually certify this (eg flu).  Sure, the hotel may want you to stay, but should they do it for free? No! You're welcome to stay, but they'll want you to keep paying.  And you're certainly able enough to get a taxi to a cheap hostel or similar or catch your flight home (even though it may be uncomfortable)

3) Ill enough that you need to go to hospital. You can't walk, eat, or similar.  What's going to happen? You tell the hotel you're this sick, and you know what's going to happen? An ambulance is going to come, and you're going to be taken to hospital.

Now this doesn't mean that they won't give you a discount if they're generous - I've heard of several doing this for friends of mine who have been stuck in bed (but not needed hospital admission), and other special cases, but there's not going to be an obligation on their part to give free accommodation to sick people.

Comment: These are nice thoughts, but they don't really answer the question ...

Comment: @MarcelC. - if there was a law, it'd surely be findable with some googling. Nevertheless, some logical deduction and common sense (as above) can show that there isn't one - there's no logical reason for hotels to give free accommodation to sick people - indeed, it's non-sensical, especially if they're ill enough that they need a hospital.  ...........of course, I'll eat my words if proven wrong.

Comment: Primo, the question is not about free accommodation. The word "free" is not mentioned in the question. Secundo, legal provisions do not always match the "common sense" ...

Comment: Yeah, ignore the 'free' part, in my actual answer I pointed out that there's no obligation on their part, and that they *might* give you a discount, but they also don't have to keep you there.  I'm not sure why I went on the 'free' tangent, my main point was that they aren't forced to keep you on, and I guess I was thinking of someone who was sick AND out of cash, for some reason.

Comment: Anyway, regarding the substance you are right. As long as one is not able to come up with the reference to a legal text, one can suppose that it does not exist.